# Can I use SUMIF with a sum range over several columns?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to make work a SUMIF formula where the sum range is across several columns (possibly a lot of them). It seems that only the first column of the sum range is taken into account.

For example, `SUMIF(A2:A4, ">="&F1, B2:D4)` sums values from `B2:B4` that match the criteria on the row, not `B2:D4`. This is surprising to me, as `SUM(B2:D4)` adds values from all rows/columns and I'd like to do the same with a criteria on the rows.

I'm working with a large number of columns and I would like a single formula, instead of adding sums for each columns. ie
`SUMIF(A2:A4, ">="&F1, B2:B4) + SUMIF(A2:A4, ">="&F1, C2:C4) + SUMIF(A2:A4, ">="&F1, D2:D4) + ...` is not an acceptable solution for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `FILTER` and then `SUM`:

```cpp
=SUM(FILTER(B2:D4,A2:A4>=F1))
```

All the `_IF(S)` functions can be replicated with their corresponding aggregate function applied on the filtered dataset, so if you can't get them to do what you're trying to do, this is usually the best alternative.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to get it to work with Sumif you'd have to duplicate the criteria across the required number of columns to match the array to be summed:

```
=SUMIF(mmult(A2:A4,{1,1,1}), ">="&F1, B2:D4)
```

or more generally

```
=SUMIF(mmult(A2:A4,sequence(1,columns(B2:D4),1,0)), ">="&F1, B2:D4)
```

It works...but maybe your accepted answer is more practical ;-)